# Linux utility to know command for a particular task

Tags: linux, command

In my initial days of using linux I usually had to search google to know the command for
doing a particular task. Once I have the command name, i can view its usage using `man command-name`.
Similarly I was thinking of some utility which can tell the command to do a particular task if the task to be done is specified as an argument and opens the man page for that command
e.g:

```
findUtilty "find all files in a directory"
output:
ls
find
```

I want to know if some utility of that kind exists, if so it will be very handy especially for newbies.
If not then i may like to implement it.

thanx,

Comment: You just need to use the answer to find the answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Not as nice as you are asking about, but

```
apropos <keyword>
```

and

```
man -k <keyword>
```

can be very useful.

Comment: apropos is just an alias for man -k, isn't it? Or does it do something different/more?

Comment: It is on my MacBook (man manpage: `-k Equivalent to apropos.`), but I have noticed that the preferred usage is a personal decision. I use `man -k`.

Comment: `man -k` is POSIX.  Many systems have an equivalent apropos command.  At least on Ubuntu, apropos has additional options, e.g. `-a` to search for commands containing *all* keywords (default is to match *any* keyword).

Answer (score 6):

Parsing natural language is hard because there are thousands of ways to rephrase one sentence. Google does it best as far as I know. So, there is no such tool. There are [handy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Core_Utilities) and [practical](http://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/index.html) manuals that makes it easy to find the right tool for the job. Also, there is a huge community behind core-utils (and linux in general), so try both forums and IRC. Often, the latter is the fastest. And people tend to parse natural language as expected :)

Answer (score 5):

[apropos](http://wiki.linuxquestions.org/wiki/apropos) will do something like you suggest.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it is: [List of Unix utilities @ Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unix_utilities)

Answer (score 2):

on Debian (and presumably derived systems) this is also useful:

```
sudo apt-cache search <keyword>
```

Comment: You dont need to be root to do this. You can drop the sudo.

Comment: interesting. I get a permission error without the sudo. Relevant files appear to be 640 root:root... How do I figure out what they should be? I'll ask on superuser... http://superuser.com/questions/37745/how-do-you-find-out-what-permissions-are-the-default-for-a-debian-package

Answer (score 0):

Few years ago `NetBSD` decided to rewrite its `apropos`. The new implementation does a full text search with results ranked in order of relevance. It comes close to what you have asked. See the output here

https://man-k.org/search?q=find+all+files+in+directory